# How to control the flow of Rendering in React Native

Tags: react-native

Let say I have a screen like this, Component B and its content is so large that may cause entire screen to wait 2 sec to render.

I'm wondering is there any way to delay the render of componentB until compA finish?

I've heard about Interaction Manager, can it use in this situation?
[image]

Comment: You can handle it with a parent state and show a loading screen meanwhile both get notified about the data. Interaction Manager is when " run code later, without delaying active animations" if that is your case, yep that is the way

Answer (score 0):

you can Use state for handle it and Use Dialog component for loading Screen , when your data load complete set your state for Hidden the Loading Screen:) if it's helpful please add point .